# Cannot Run Executable File Created by Swift on Linux

Tags: swift, linux, macos, arm, executable

I have made a command line application in Swift. When I run the executable product it produces on my Mac, everything is fine and it works as expected. But when I copy the executable over to my Linux machine, it doesn't work and produces the following error:

```
-sh: ./script: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I assume that this has something to do with there being a difference in acceptable executable formats between the two machines but am not sure. And if that is true, I am not sure how to build the executable product in a format that will be able to run on my Linux machine.

Here are the details on my Linux machine:

```
  Operating System: FSLC Wayland 3.1 (dunfell)
            Kernel: Linux 5.4.85+gedb81d8afdfe
      Architecture: arm64
```

How can I fix this to get the executable running on my Linux machine?

Comment: Your suspicion is correct, the executable formats used by macOS ([Mach-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O)) and Linux ([ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)) are completely incompatible.

Comment: @Alexander do you know if there is any way to produce an executable with the linux file format as a product for the Swift command line application?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: You'll want to look into cross-compiling. I'm not sure what the state of this is for Swift at the moment, but this thread might help: https://forums.swift.org/t/cross-compiling-macos-to-linux/34003